# DIR function retrieving the file, but not the file name

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Dir(folder & "*.xl*")
MsgBox (MyFile)

Dim OpenTime As Date
OpenTime = FileDateTime(folder & MyFile)
```

In which `folder` is a public string set in a different module. And it's value is retrieved like such `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`

Now the problem I face is that `MsgBox (MyFile)` returns an empty messagebox, but the value of `OpenTime` is consistent with that of the first file in the selected folder.

So that leaves me to believe that folder is set correctly, which I confirmed using the direct window:

```
debug.Print(folder)
D:\CLM\Enquete\Aardappel
```

Printing the variables `MyFile` and `OpenTime` resulted in this:

```
debug.print(MyFile)

debug.Print(OpenTime)
12-6-2018 15:04:18
```

Any thougts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final path pattern has no slash before file name. Change it to:

```
folder = "D:\CLM\Enquete\Aardappel\"
```

or if folder path is not hardcoded, to:

```
folder = folder & "\"
```

Comment: mehh so simple. Interesting though to see that the FileDateTime does work without that \

Comment: @luuklag FileDateTime retrieves data of the folder not the file (dir returns empty string)

Comment: @BrakNicku ah I see, that is by coincidence the same as that of the first file, as that was opened last.